# Как сделать cross origin запросы по /login в Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring

Настроил `Spring Security` на работу с `JWT`. Сам мой сервис `stateless` и отдает `json`'ы. Проблема в том, что при попытке получить токен через браузер у меня возниает слудающая ошибка:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:7345/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

C обычным контроллером я мог бы поставить просто аннотацию `CrossOrigin`, но тут если создам такой контроллер, то он перекроет мои настройки в `Spring Security`.

Что делать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить глобальную конфигурацию CORS запросов

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

Более подробно можно почитать в документации [27.3.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html)

Comment: Пробовал так сделать. Ошибка осталась: http://joxi.ru/D2PGDK9cQzK7m3

Comment: Насколько я помню, ты фронт пишешь на angular 2. При запросе в ангуляре нужно указать опцию withCredentials. [пример такого запроса](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38615675/5308586)

Comment: Немного не в тему. Никак не могу понять, что происходит. Делаю запрос через `postman`: http://joxi.net/krDGOLBcQXqgAp . Через `Angular2`: http://joxi.net/BA0Np9EUGXxvmy . Запрос делаю так: http://joxi.ru/BA0Np9EUGXjvmy .

Comment: Согласно рекомендациям [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), еще одна [ссылка](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), где описано более понятным языком. Если кратко, GET и POST запросы могут вызывать side эффекты на сервере, поэтому перед ними браузер посылает запрос OPTIONS на проверку возможности обслуживания запросов. OPTIONS запросы отправляют и обрабатывают только заголовки - [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

Comment: Сделал так, чтобы в ответ был отдан только заголовки при `OPTIONS` запросе. В итоге получаю следующую ошибку: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:7345/login. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: `registry.addMapping("/**")
   .allowedOrigins("*")`

Comment: Сделал - ошибка осталась.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59981/discussion-between-ruslan-masgutov-and-faoxis).

Answer (score 1):

Возможно ответ не на заданный вопрос, но он решит твою проблему. Если есть nginx, то ты им обслуживаешь статику и перенаправляешь запросы на бэк(обслуживание spa приложений через nginx). Для локального режима разработки у webpack-dev-server есть настройка proxy для проксирования запроса на бэк. На фронте в запросах вообще не указываешь хост куда отправлять запрос. В этом случае вообще не требуется настройки в spring.

**UPDATE**

`const METADATA = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
    baseUrl: '/',
    hostUrl: 'http://localhost:3001'
};
//---
devServer: {
         // конфиги..
        proxy: {
            '/api/*': {
                target: METADATA.hostUrl,
                secure: false
            }
        }
        // конфиги...
    }`

Comment: А не подскажешь, что должно быть в типовом `webpack.config.js` для запуска на `angular 2` с проксированием ? Никогда еще не работал с `webpack`. Будет вообще круто, если у тебя есть пример. :)

Comment: Добавил в ответ часть своего конфига `webpack.config.js` для проксирования запросов

Comment: А в каком файлеэто должно быть ? В `webpack.config.js` ? Еще не очень понимаю как это запускать. Если я выполняю команду `webpack`, то у меня собирается один большой `js` файл, но это никак не влияет на то, что происходит при выполнении команды `npm start`.

Comment: Команда webpack - это компиляция исходников для дистрибуции, npm start - этот компиляция и запуск dev сервера. [мой старый шаблон для инициализации проекта](https://github.com/rmasgutov/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.common.js)

Comment: Клева! Единственное, не могу понять как правильно проксировать. Сделал так:    `proxy: {
            '/back': {
                target: 'http://localhost:7345'
            }
        }` . Проблема в том, что не обрубается начало с `/back`и получается при запросе `/back/login` я попадаю на `http://localhost:7345/back/login`, а надо `http://localhost:7345/login`.

Comment: `proxy: { '/back': { target: 'http://localhost:7345', pathRewrite: {'^/back' : ''}} }`

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Заработало! Какое-то количество вопросов назад ты говорил, что если в `index.html` поставить `<base href="/front/">`, то потом можно проксировать это через `webpack`. Столкнулся с тем, что он не хочет перенаправлять запрос к себе же вот так: `'/front': {
                pathRewrite: {'^/front': ''},
                target: '/'
            }` . Пробовал различные варианты с `target` (и без него) - ничего не выходит.

Comment: target явно задай